# Set StaticText control text using pure Windows API, no MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am attempting to write a very small graphical program for Windows in the Visual C++ using pure Windows API. Program consists of the one dialog with couple buttons and static text control. Dialog is initializaed from resource. What I need to do is when dialog initialized, static text is filled with some value, that is dynamicallt computed. I am stuck at his point, because I completely don't know how to change static text value on the dialog dynamically. Please advise.
I assume that must be call to SetWindowText(), but the question is - how do I determine hWnd for the particular static text on the dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your resource script the control would have a particular ID (e.g. `IDC_STATIC`). The simplest way to change its text in that case is:

```
SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDC_STATIC, L"the new text");
```

Alternatively, you can use `GetDlgItem()` to get the handle to the control using its ID and then call `SetWindowText()`.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I need.